# tornadoweb motor move document between collections

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado

Is there a smart way for moving document from one collection to another? I want to read document from collection 1, do insert in collection 2 and remove document from 1.

It's doable with 3 steps, but maybe there is a smarter way?

Greets!

Comment: You mean using Tornado or in general in MongoDB? At least in Mongo there's no way to do it simpler. Operations in Mongo are atomic.

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB 2.5.4 (beta), there's a new $out operator for the aggregation pipeline: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/. This will overwrite the whole target collection, so I guess this is not what you want.

There's no other atomic operation across collections, AFAIK, so you'll need the 3 steps.